# Handle every request in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, routes, request, handle

I have laravel project and I want to create access log table. in route file is it possible handle every request and its parameters to store in database.

Comment: this won't be too good for your database, but its possible

Answer (score 1):

You can [create middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware) and handle all request with it. Then put all your routes in a [group](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-groups) to apply your middleware.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'yourMiddleware'], function () {
    // All your routes
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Create your own service provider and register it, then in `boot` method create script that logs requests to database.

Example:

```
public function boot()
{
    if (! app()->runningInConsole()) {
        App\Request::create(['payload'=>serialize(app('request')->all())]);
    }
}
```